# How to create a Coordinates instance in selenium-java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this use case: given a pair (x, y) with respect to the upper left corner of the window, I need the mouse to click the (x, y) location. This action has no relation to any element on the page. The Mouse class has this method: `click(Coordinates where)`. However, I can't find a way to create a Coordinates instance to call the `click` method. So, how can I solve my use case?

Answer (score 0):

**Actions** class of **org.openqa.selenium.interactions** has a method **moveByOffset(int xOffset, int yOffset)** which will move the mouse from its current position (or 0,0) by the given offset.

You can move to your offset and then use the click() method of **Actions** class to click at new offset.

EX:

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveByOffset(xOffset,yOffset).build().perform();
act.click().build().perform();
```

I haven't tired this though. But it should work.